# Is it possible to completely monkey-patch a class from a library in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to add some very fundamental functionality to a library (namely scikit-learn). However, I'd prefer to not directly modify the library itself, as a) even in my own testing, I'd rather have the ability to turn the functionality on and off and b) this is very possibly functionality that does not belong in the main code base for the library.

What I'd like to do is to monkey-patch a base class (in this case sklearn.base.BaseEstimator) such that when other classes within the library import/derive from the class, they get my modified class instead. Here's what I have so far:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn import base

class InstrumentedEstimator(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'called'
        super(InstrumentedEstimator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

sklearn.base.BaseEstimator = InstrumentedEstimator
base.BaseEstimator = InstrumentedEstimator
BaseEstimator = InstrumentedEstimator

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
RandomForestClassifier()
```

This doesn't work - i.e., `RandomForestClassifier()` does not print `called`. I suspect the main reason here is that when looking at `RandomForestClassifier`'s hierarchy, the ultimate parent class that derives from BaseEstimator is `sklearn.ensemble.base.BaseEnsemble`. Looking at sklearn/ensemble/base.py, one sees the following:

```
from ..base import BaseEstimator
```

Is it even possible to monkey-patch this style of imports in Python? And more importantly, is it possible (within the context of a program, obviously), to monkey-patch all instances of this class regardless of where and how they're imported?

Ideally, the end-game would be something like this:

```
import my_module
from sklearn.(anything) import SomeEstimator

SomeEstimator()  # this runs my code in addition to SomeEstimator's code
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `BaseEstimator` doesn't define an `__init__` method, so its children don't call `super.__init__`. If you monkey patch `BaseEnsemble` however, you will see the effects. Replacing the class is not very effective as other classes have already subclassed the original class, but you can replace a method on the class like so:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaseEnsemble, RandomForestClassifier

old_init = BaseEnsemble.__init__

def new_init(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'called'
    old_init(*args, **kwargs)

BaseEnsemble.__init__ = new_init

RandomForestClassifier()
```

This does indeed print `called`.

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I didn't notice the lack of `__init__`. I guess I just assumed that it would have one!